# Failure | SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This test failure is killing me. I'm following along with the railstutorial.org e-book. I've researched this failure as much as I can. I've read up on testing over and over, but I'm just missing something, and I have been stuck on this issue for nearly a week. I'm at wits end. Thank you for any insight.

rake test results in:

```
  1) Failure:
SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil [/Users/test_user/app/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:

--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id: 762146111, first_name: "Michael", middle_name: "James", last_name: "Example", suffix: "Jr", created_at: "2015-08-01 14:13:26", updated_at: "2015-08-01 14:13:27", email: "michael@example.com", password_digest: "$2a$04$.AOr7J8q/Ft7Gu3HTNWjDet5kU2O8uFwV9l...", remember_digest: "$2a$04$./yszAudU5o/tovax413r.poDLg5N33a0XD...">
+nil
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :remember_token

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  has_secure_password


  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # returns a url-safe random string of 20 characters, each character having 64 possibilities
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(:remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
  module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

sessions_helper_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

users.yml

```
michael:
  first_name: Michael
  middle_name: James
  last_name: Example
  suffix: Jr
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failing test makes no sense to me : the user is never logged in, and still the test expects `current_user` to returns a user.

Try with the 2 following tests :

```
test "current_user returns right user when session is set" do
  log_in @user
  assert_equal @user, current_user
  assert is_logged_in?
end

test "current_user returns no user when session is nil" do
  assert_nil current_user
  assert !is_logged_in?
end
```

Comment: I would argue that it makes sense to have the test and I would like to make it work.  We "remember(@user)" in setup, which should set the cookie that "current_user" needs to return a user.
Why does it not ? check out "remember" in user.rb and "remember(user)" in sessions_helper.rb.  should that not yield a positive result in "current_user" in sessions_helper.rb ?

Comment: xyious - This was exactly what I needed to do. Strangely enough, I gave up on that ROR attempt some six months ago, recently started the whole tutorial over again, ran into the exact same problem today, Google'd the error message, came across this post, which I was surprised to see that I had originally posted back in August, and as it turns out, following your advice was exactly what I needed to do. Thank you. It was a silly typo.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, learn [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) instead of test/unit.

Secondly, what's your version of Rails?

Generally the code you are presenting is honestly a really shitty implementation of login/logout functions. You don't need to store these functions in helper (controller can't access helper functions, at least not without magic, and you most definitely will need current_user function in your controllers), you don't need some rememberance 'tokens', and you don't need to mix 'cookies' and 'session' variables (by default 'session' IS special cookie, already signed/checked by Rails itself).

So just rewrite that example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # validations, etc., what you have in your initial example
  # just forget about 'remember token' and such stuff
end

class ApplicationController
  # we don't want these methods to become actions
  private

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= (session[:user_id] && User.find(session[:user_id]))
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def log_out
    # it's good idea to clear EVERYTHING from session on log-out, not just user_id
    reset_session
    @current_user = nil
  end
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

Yeah, that looks much better. Unless you see a really really good reason to make your code look like mess with all that 'token' stuff.

Now to the specs!

1. Install [rspec-rails](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) (basically, add couple of lines to your Gemfile)
2. `rails g rspec:controller sessions` in your terminal
3. Something like that in your newly generated spec:

-

```
describe SesssionsController
  # move your fixtures to appropriate folder beforehand (basically, from test/something to spec/something)
  fixtures :users

  before do
    @michael = users(:michael)
  end

  it 'logs user in'
    post :create, session: {email: 'michael@example.com', password: 'password'}
    expect(controller.send(:current_user)).to_not be_nil
    expect(controller.send(:current_user).id).to eq @michael.id
  end
end
```

Didn't test that code, I must admit, so if you encounter some errors which are not obvious, feel free to ask for further help in comments to my reply.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `remember` method in the User model.

```
def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(:remember_token))
end
```

should be

```
def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
```

I'm not sure on the specifics of why the original doesn't work, but putting the `remember_token` there as a symbol is what's breaking it.

In reference to the current best answer:

Adding a call to `log_in` in the test only circumvents the problem above, and actually makes the test pointless. What you're trying to test here, in this test:

```
test 'current_user returns right user when session is nil' do
  assert_equal @user, current_user
  assert is_logged_in?
end
```

is that the part of the `current_user` method that handles users that *have* a signed cookie, but *don't* have an active session, is working (logging the user in, and assigning them to `@current_user`).

```
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
          #### THIS BIT ####
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user     
    end
          ##################
  end
end
```

So by just logging in the user in the setup, you are passing the `current_user` method a user with an active session, which means it's not ever reaching the part of the method you're trying to test.